# How to use named tuples with Entity Framework raw SQL 'SqlQuery' method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm stuck using EF5 on a legacy project. In it, I wish to return two fields from the database using some custom, "raw" Sql with EF. When I try and return the values into a named tuple, the values are always the 'default value' of the value-type. So it's not mapping the database value to the named tuple.

Does EF5 support this concept? If yes, could someone explain what I've done wrong, then?

```
const string userQuery = @"
SELECT Top 1 ThirdPartyIdentifier, ThemeId 
FROM Users
WHERE ThirdPartyIdentifier IS NOT NULL AND ThemeId > 0";

var (thirdPartyIdentifier, themeId) = SqlServerContext
    .Database
    .SqlQuery<(string ThirdPartyIdentifier, int ThemeId)>(userQuery)
    .Single();


#region Assembly EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
// C:\Users\pewpew\.nuget\packages\entityframework\5.0.0\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll
// Decompiled with ICSharpCode.Decompiler 7.1.0.6543
#endregion
```

I've ran the query manually against the database and it does return some values. While the above only returns `null` and `0`.

Comment: To clarify, you're referring to Entity Framework 5.x for .NET Framework 4.x and _not_ EF Core 5.x?

Comment:  Hi @Dai - I believe so - Yes. I've also updated the OP with some more info to help confirm/clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does EF5 support this concept?

- No, it does not.
- To my knowledge, all versions of Entity Framework and Entity Framework Core 1.x and 2.0 only support binding query-result columns to `class` types which must have parameterless constructors [and mutable property setters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt) (though they don't need to be `public`).
- Entity Framework Core 2.1 [added support for "convention-based" entity class constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors), but (as of August 2022, in EF Core 6) still does not offer any way to configure how constructors are mapped.
- But crucially: you cannot map to fields, even exposed and mutable fields.

  - And `ValueTuple` *only* has fields. Joy.

Entity Framework uses the functionality from its inner `ObjectContext.Translate` to map from query results to registered/configured entity class types and non-table query results to *complex-types* (which are not embued with entity types' magic in `DbContext` but still useful nontheless).

- You *can* use "anonymous types" in a `.Select` projection in a Linq-to-EF query, but anonymous-types are pretty awful for other reasons - but it's often the only choice with EF.
- Before anyone says "use a `record class`!", unfortunately the OP isn't using C# 9.0, and [there's still](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/28350) [open issues](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/27281) [with `record` types](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20record%20class%20select).

So you need to be *a tad verbose* with `.Database.SqlQuery`, but it isn't too bad: a simple mutable POCO with property-setters will work - if you can hold-your-nose about EF 5 disregarding constructors (*grumble*):

```cs
public class UserQueryResult
{
    public String ThirdPartyIdentifier { get; internal set; }
    public Int32  ThemeId              { get; internal set; }
}

const string userQuery = @"
SELECT
    TOP 1
    ThirdPartyIdentifier,
    ThemeId 
FROM
    Users
WHERE
    ThirdPartyIdentifier IS NOT NULL
    AND
    ThemeId > 0;
";

UserQueryResult result = await SqlServerContext
    .Database
    .SqlQuery<UserQueryResult>( userQuery )
    .SingleAsync( cancellationToken )
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

---